# Hibernate - How to efficiently fetch a big object graph?

Tags: hibernate

For a project, I have to read a list of objects out of a database. The object type is a big object graph consisting of a lot of associated objects. When I execute the select query to get a list of all the objects in the database, Hibernate not only executes 1, but 45 additional queries. Still, it seems that the objects are lazy loaded.

But what I need is efficiently loading list of the WHOLE objects. What would be the best way to do this?

I first thought of using fetch joins but with so many associations this could become a real pain. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: do you need to load the entire object graph, or just some properties on the root level object?

Comment: The entire object graph.

Answer (score 3):

Fetch joins and caching (or combination thereof) are basically the only ways to improve performance here; whether they will work for you highly depends on what your entities look like and what it is you're trying to do.

Caching is helpful for many-to-one dependencies with (somewhat) limited number of (ideally immutable) instances - e.g. looking up references. Fetch joins can be used for all other one-to-ones and many-to-ones; trying to fetch nested collections gets out of hand *very* quickly.

One additional trick which is applicable in certain cases is pre-loading (some) lazy dependent entities (if you know what they are beforehand, of course) into session before running your query. That way you don't have to deal with performance / memory issues of 2nd level cache for cases where that's impractical.

All that said, if the 45 additional queries you've mentioned are *per entity* in your list, you'll probably have to make a trade-off somewhere and cache / fetch some dependencies letting the others being loaded via subsequent selects.